# How to uninstall aws-cdk

Tags: node-modules

```
which -a cdk
cdk is /usr/local/bin/cdk
cdk is /usr/local/bin/cdk
```

I am trying to uninstall it, but finding no luck.

```
(.env) [senthilx@88665a371033:~]$ npm uninstall aws-cdk -g
up to date in 0.021s
(.env) [senthilx@88665a371033:~]$ /usr/local/bin/npm uninstall aws-cdk -g

up to date, audited 1 package in 119ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
(.env) [senthilx@88665a371033:~]$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/cdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 senthilx  admin  35 May 27 15:22 /usr/local/bin/cdk -> ../lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk
```

Any troubleshooting steps?

Comment: It seems to me you are doing it in some sort of virtual environment. Maybe destroy the environment or just uninstall it outside? I would also suggest to put `-g` after `uninstall`. Not sure if `-g` can come at the end

Answer (score 1):

Remove `/usr/local/bin/cdk` and then `../lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk`.

Comment: So, that will be a brute force way, and I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran Did you find a way?